# Custom filter in array adaptor

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-filter, android-filterable

I want to search the custom listview (Used arrayadaptor) items based on the user input.I have already implements filterable class in my custom listview, But for optimizing the cache memory i have used holder to carry the current row. Now its become much complicated to get the item based on the user input.

Can anyone help me to sort out the issue ?

My main class is,

```
public class ambulanceActivity extends Activity{
dbhelper db4;
ListView lstview_Items;
int images =  R.drawable.call;
final ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> mArrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ambulance_list);
    EditText inputSearch=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    lstview_Items=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    db4 = new dbhelper(getApplicationContext());
    db4.creteDB();
    Cursor checkerA = db4.getDetails();
    checkerA.moveToFirst();
    while (!checkerA.isAfterLast()) {
        mArrayList.add(checkerA.getString(checkerA
                .getColumnIndex("ambname")));
        mArrayList1.add(checkerA.getString(checkerA
                .getColumnIndex("ambnum")));
        checkerA.moveToNext();
    }
    checkerA.close();
    final CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,mArrayList,images,mArrayList1);
    lstview_Items.setAdapter(adapter);
    lstview_Items.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
      });
     }
   }
```

And my custom listview is,I have just implement the filterable class here

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String> implements Filterable{
Context con;
int images;
ArrayList<String> names;
ArrayList<String> number;

public CustomAdapter(Con c, ArrayList<String> mArrayList,int imgs, ArrayList<String> num) {
    super(c, R.layout.list_entry,R.id.contact,mArrayList);
    this.con=c;
    this.images=imgs;
    this.names=mArrayList;
    this.number=num;
}
class  MyViewHolder extends Activity
{
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView myContactName;
    TextView myContactNumber;

    MyViewHolder(View v)
    {
        myImage=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.police);
        myContactName=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        myContactNumber=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact);

    }
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder=null;
    if (row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry, parent, false);
        holder=new MyViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    ImageView call=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.police);
    call.setTag(position);
    call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL");
            Uri data = Uri.parse("tel:"+number.get(position).toString());
            intent.setData(data);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    TextView contact=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.contact);
    holder.myImage.setImageResource(images);
    holder.myContactName.setText(names.get(position));
    holder.myContactNumber.setText(number.get(position));
    return row;
    }
   }
```

Comment: You did not implement a filter at all. What problem do you have with a cache?

Comment: your data model is sqlitedb (`db4.getDetails();`), so why don't you use a `[S]imple]CursorAdapter` ???

Comment: i don't know how to implement a filter in this customized listview ,i have tried, but not worked. could you please help me to sort out the issue

Comment: see `FilterQueryProvider` class

Comment: @pskink, i have to add an image with multiple text items in my listview, moreover while once click the call button it should make call to corresponding number, For making the listview more dynamic and customizable i think arrayadaptor is better

Comment: no, it's not, if your data model is sqlitedb the natural and the most obvious is to use [Simple]CursorAdapter, in most cases you dont need any custom [Simple]CursorAdapter, when you need to map something more than simple TextViews use a ViewBinder class

Comment: @greenapps, For the purpose of optimizing the listview only i have used viewholder concept here, Now i am blank that how to use the filter method here

Comment: you don't need view holder pattern, in 95% of cases it is useless, what you need however is CursorAdapter and FilterQueryProvider

Comment: @pskink, But now the prblm is related with filter?

Comment: @pskink , please watch this tutorial , you will realize the usage of viewholder in a large listview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTEiRiMaQ7M

Comment: the guy from that tutorial misuses view holder and view reusing: they are completly two different things and i see that poeple on SO have the same problem: using view holder pattern you can speedup your ListView maybe by 5 or 10 ms (and not 175% lol) when scrolling from top to bottom, that's why i say it is useless

Comment: Using viewholder yes or no has nothing to do with implementing a filter.  So come to the point: where are the problems?

Comment: @Sreeraj "But now the prblm is related with filter" i know, and i told you not to complicate your code: just use SimpleCursorAdapter and custom FilterQueryProvider, that's all

Comment: @greenapps, the problem is i don't know how to implement filter or whatever the methods that i have to use to filter the items in my listview , it will be great full if you can write a piece of code to sort out the issue.